# UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToFile correct page size based on locale

Tags: ios, swift, pdf, printing

In my app I generate pdf's (which can be printed or sent later) 
and I can not find a proper way of determining size of paper :

```
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToFile(pdfURL().path, CGRectZero, nil)
```

By default creates pdf **ANSI A (612.0, 792.0)** which is OK for US & Canada (+some more countries) but for the rest it should be **ISO216 A4 (595,842)**

Basically I need iOS version of this :

```
NSPrintInfo.sharedPrintInfo().paperSize
```

Am I missing something or the only way on iOS is to check locale by hand ?

Comment: Have you tried running the app in a different locale?

Comment: Yes, I have 612.0, 792.0 always. Just like Apple documentations says UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToFile   bounds: A rectangle that specifies the default size and location of PDF pages. (This value is used as the default media box for each new page.) The origin of the rectangle should typically be (0, 0). Specifying an empty rectangle (CGRectZero) sets the default page size to 8.5 by 11 inches (612 by 792 points).

Comment: You might have to do localisation hacks to check their locale :-(, I'm sure there are better ways but I can't help, sorry.

Comment: Thanks anyway. localisation check is what i'm currently have. I'll wait and see maybe some1 has some other solutions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## **Solution :**

Since US Letter (ANSI A) is used only in North America, Bolivia, Colombia, Panama, Venezuela, the Philippines, Costa Rica and Chile. We can just take country code from our current locale and check if it's in list of those countries.

SWIFT 3 (Extension) :

```
extension NSLocale {

    struct StandardPageDimensions  {
        static let ANSI_A        = CGSize(width:612,height:792)
        static let ANSI_B        = CGSize(width:792,height:1224)
        static let ANSI_C        = CGSize(width:1584,height:1224)
        static let ANSI_D        = CGSize(width:2448,height:1584)
        static let ANSI_E        = CGSize(width:3168,height:2448)

        static let ISO216_A0     = CGSize(width:2384,height:3370)
        static let ISO216_A1     = CGSize(width:1684,height:2384)
        static let ISO216_A2     = CGSize(width:1190,height:1684)
        static let ISO216_A3     = CGSize(width:842,height:1190)
        static let ISO216_A4     = CGSize(width:595,height:842)
        static let ISO216_A5     = CGSize(width:420,height:595)
        static let ISO216_A6     = CGSize(width:298,height:420)
        static let ISO216_A7     = CGSize(width:210,height:298)
        static let ISO216_A8     = CGSize(width:148,height:210)
    }

    static let ANSI_A_Countries : Set<String> = ["US","CA","MX","CU","DO","GT","CR","SV","HN","BO","CO","VE","PH","CL"]

    //If you want to use Locale use regionCode
    static func defaultPaperSize()->CGSize {
        let locale = self.current
        return ANSI_A_Countries.contains( locale.regionCode ?? "" ) ? StandardPageDimensions.ANSI_A : StandardPageDimensions.ISO216_A4
    }

    //otherwise cast to NSLocale
    //        static func defaultPaperSize()->CGSize {
    //            let locale = self.current as NSLocale
    //            return ANSI_A_Countries.contains( locale.object(forKey: NSLocale.Key.countryCode) as! String ) ? StandardPageDimensions.ANSI_A : StandardPageDimensions.ISO216_A4
    //        }

}
```

**The reason I did not use Locale.currencyCode because CurrencyCode not always equals CountryCode.**

**ISO 3166-2 != ISO 4217**

You might need to update ANSI_A_Countries to match Currencies ISO's.
For example Bolivia, Bolíviano Country ((https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-2:BO)
) ISO Code is specified as BO but currency Codes only have BOL.

SWIFT 2 :

```
struct StandardPageDimensions  {
    static let ANSI_A        = CGSizeMake(612,792)
    static let ANSI_B        = CGSizeMake(792,1224)
    static let ANSI_C        = CGSizeMake(1584,1224)
    static let ANSI_D        = CGSizeMake(2448,1584)
    static let ANSI_E        = CGSizeMake(3168,2448)

    static let ISO216_A0     = CGSizeMake(2384,3370)
    static let ISO216_A1     = CGSizeMake(1684,2384)
    static let ISO216_A2     = CGSizeMake(1190,1684)
    static let ISO216_A3     = CGSizeMake(842,1190)
    static let ISO216_A4     = CGSizeMake(595,842)
    static let ISO216_A5     = CGSizeMake(420,595)
    static let ISO216_A6     = CGSizeMake(298,420)
    static let ISO216_A7     = CGSizeMake(210,298)
    static let ISO216_A8     = CGSizeMake(148,210)
}

let ANSI_A_Countries : Set<String> = ["US","CA","MX","CU","DO","GT","CR","SV","HN","BO","CO","VE","PH","CL"]

func defaultSizeForCurrentLocale()->CGSize {
    let locale = NSLocale.currentLocale()
    return ANSI_A_Countries.contains( locale.objectForKey(NSLocaleCountryCode) as! String ) ? StandardPageDimensions.ANSI_A : StandardPageDimensions.ISO216_A4
}
```

Comment: This is a nice workaround that looks to work in most cases on an important topic. However settings based on countries (as in the other answer) are not settings based on paper size layout preferences? It is just not a answer on the topic, it is a quick and very dirty solution. We should not do that.

Answer (score 5):

```
let bestPaper = UIPrintPaper.bestPaper(forPageSize: CGSize.zero, withPapersFrom: [])
```

Examining `bestPaper.paperSize.width` & `bestPaper.paperSize.height`, you get localized results based on the current region:

United States: `612 x 792`, which is US Letter

United Kingdom: `595.2756 x 841.8898`, which is A4

Note that it’s not documented that specifying an empty page size and empty paper list will generate this default, but that is the behavior I see.

Comment: I think this answer is the correct answer on the topic. The question is what paper size does the locale settings suggest? The answer countries static let ANSI_A_Countries : Set<String> = ["US","CA","MX","CU","DO","GT","CR","SV","HN","BO","CO","VE","PH","CL"] are an indirect assumption and not selectable by the user. It is the OS locale settings feature and not the apps job to set preferred paper size layout. If the OS locale settings features do not supply a user interface to make the user aware, it is not the apps responsibility, but the OS. We can't have apps covering the OS as a solution?

Comment: The issue that "it’s not documented that specifying an empty page size and empty paper list will generate this default, but that is the behavior I see" is a documentation issue of the OS supplier and also here it is not the responsibility of the app but the OS documentation. In fact it works very well. I hope it will be documented so this is the official path. Also so it might not be defunct by mistake by the OS supplier. What I understand there are no other official recommendations on this topic? And nothing else that actually works supplying the answer on this topic.